# Is there a way to optimize this case of catastrophic regex backtracking?

Tags: regex, performance

So I have come up with the following regex:

```
([^\s\\]+(?:\\.[^\s\\]*)*)(?:.*?)(\S+\.php\b)
```

Test link: https://regex101.com/r/NV6Bk4/4

It matches the binary and the script name of a command line. Example:

```
php --strict myscript.php --arg=value
```

matches `php` and `myscript.php` in group(1) and group(2).

The problem is this part in the middle: `(?:.*?)`, it leads to combinatorial explosion, slowing down the regex for large inputs. Is there a way to optimize this? Since there is no pattern I can't think of anything.

To clarify, the rule that I'm trying to match is:
Match any path to a command, possibly containing escaped whitespace. Ignore any arguments following it. Match a file ending in .php, ignore anything that follows it. The command should be in group(1), the filename should be in group(2).

Comment: What environment are you running the regex in?

Comment: Actually, it is more important to know the actual rules. What is being matched and why? The problem is obvious: consequent adjoining patterns can match the same type of chars.

Comment: It will run in Java 8.

Comment: Check `^([^\s\\]*+(?:\\.[^\s\\]*)*).*?(\S+\.php\b)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NV6Bk4/5). If your matches start at the beginning of a string use `^` and use a possessive quantifier with the first negated character class

Comment: That looks promising! Is there a way to make it `match()`? This is unfortunately a constraint that I have.

Comment: What do you mean by   `match`? If you mean you need to use this pattern inside `matches()` method add `.*` at the end.

Comment: This is a Java pecularity, it tries to match the whole string. You can try it at https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html, there is a `matches()` column that will tell you if it matched, as opposed to simply `find()`.

Comment: Adding a `.*` at the end works! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following "fix" with `Matcher#matches()`:

```
([^\s\\]*+(?:\\.[^\s\\]*)*).*?(\S+\.php\b).*
```

In Java

```
String regex = "([^\\s\\\\]*+(?:\\\\.[^\\s\\\\]*)*).*?(\\S+\\.php\\b).*";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NV6Bk4/6). Note that a literal `.` outside of a character class must be escaped. Compile the pattern with `Pattern.DOTALL` if the string may have line breaks.

As you see, the `.*?` part matches any char, and `(?:\\.[^\s\\]*)*` before it can match any 0 or more chars (so, it is kind of optional) and the next adjoining pattern to `.*?` from the left is `[^\s\\]+` that can match the same chars as `.*?`. That means, the regex engine may backtrack to the first subpattern, and that creates a lot of ways to match the string, commonly named as catastrophic backtracking.

If you disallow backtracking into the first negated character class with `*+` possessive quantifier, it will already work much more reliably.

Add `.*` at the end to make it work with `.matches()` as this method requires a full string match.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Outstanding!